# go code coverage report in Jenkins with cobertura plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, code-coverage, cobertura

I have installed cobertura plugin in Jenkins and ran unit tests with below command `#go test -cover -p 1 $PKGS | go-junit-report > report.xml`. I could see report.xml is created with code coverage but I see below error in Jenkins console. Could you please let us know what is the issue and how to resolve this.

```
/bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1811800402022775798.sh
[Cobertura] Publishing Cobertura coverage report...
FATAL: Unable to find coverage results
java.io.IOException: <workspace>/report.xml is not a cobertura coverage report, please check your report pattern
    at hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher$ParseReportCallable.invoke(CoberturaPublisher.java:566)
    at hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher$ParseReportCallable.invoke(CoberturaPublisher.java:536)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)
    at hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher.perform(CoberturaPublisher.java:343)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
[Cobertura] No coverage results were found using the pattern '**/report.xml' relative to '<some directory>'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you generate the XML report(s) for Cobertura?
Build step 'Publish Cobertura Coverage Report' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps to generate coverage report (for go language)

[gocovxml](https://github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml)

Install gocov xml using below commands

```
$ go get github.com/axw/gocov/...
$ go get github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml
```

execute go test command if you have multiple packages

```
gocov test $PKGS -p 1 | gocov-xml > report.xml
```

Provide report.xml in publish cobertura coverage report (Post build action in Jenkins)

```
**/report.xml
```